# In how many ways can you rearrange CANADA?

Tags: combinatorics

I'm trying to solve the following question which is in the permutations unit:

> In how many ways can all the letters of the word CANADA be arranged if the consonants must always be in the order in which they occur in the word itself?

I have no idea where to start, any hints would be appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: http://www.sosmath.com/CBB/viewtopic.php?t=9756

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Select three out of six positions for the consonants, fill tme in order, then fill the rest with "A"s. So that's $6\choose 3$.